# Is there any way to get a bearer token for each user in Azure and use for authentication against a web API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, bearer-token

It seems a very simple question and hard to imagine Microsoft does not have a solution for it but after Googling for days I cannot find an answer for it, at least not a simple answer. I am developing a set of APIs with fastAPI to run some jobs in backend based on requests. Every user in our company should be able to call those APIs. Also,  some of those APIs need to be called from Jenkins jobs and some other similar tools. Normally, I would use LDAP for authentication and generate a token for each user, store it in database and allow users call functions using their tokens. Tokens could expire after 6 months or so.

Company's new policy is getting away from LDAP and use Azure active directory and OIDC protocol. I though maybe I can use this opportunity to offload token authentication and maintenance to Azure but after a week googling, still cannot find how should I do that and even if it is possible with Azure. Every solution that I have found either needs passing client secret to the end user/Jenkins job which is not acceptable or get a token in interactive way which might work for human user but not Jenkins jobs and pipeline. Additionally, almost all of them require scripting/coding on the client side and using MSAL or Identity library. Is there any way that end users can get a token from Azure, pass it to my API, and I use the token for authentication? Hopefully a token with long lifetime so it can be added to pipelines.

I have looked at:
username-password flow. Microsoft does not recommend it and doesn't look good as it needs password in the command line/script
device-code flow. require interactive user and need some scripting on client side. (at least that was my understanding).
service principal for pipelines but if I understand it correctly, it needs client secret and tokens have short life.

Basically, I am looking for a way that end users can go grab a token from somewhere and send it to API using a curl command, then I authenticate and run the job at the backend. Is it possible with Azure?

**Update:**

English is not my first language so maybe that is why I couldn't clearly explain what I am trying to do. My actual system is more complicated but let's say I have two APIs. The first API receives a file and archive it. The second API returns the list of archived file.
I am not talking about backend job or what happen in backend or why I am archiving a file. I am just asking how can I authenticate the user who send the file or the user who ask for the list of the archived file. Jenkins server1 would send file1 and I just need to know if it is actually Jenkins server1's service account who sent the file and if user1 asked for list of files, it is actually the user1. In case of user1, interactive authentication is acceptable but in case of Jenkins service account, it can't be interactive and I cannot share the client secret with them. Also, when I said token, I meant something like token, it could be jwt, certificate,... I just don't want to generate certificate or jwt one by one for them. In my preferred solution the end user should be able to go to Azure portal or somewhere and get a token, certificate, jwt or whatever and call the API and send the certificate, jwt,... Then API asks Azure, do you know the person who provide this certificate, JWT? if yes, API continue, if not, refuse to archive the file or return the list of files.

Answer (score 0):

A backend job should not operate with user level access tokens. Instead it should present its own workload credential to get access tokens, then use that to call APIs. Building your own token stores is also a security risk. The way this should work with OAuth and OIDC is as follows:

**USERS**

They run an application that enables them to access files. The app might be a web app, desktop app or console app. The app uses the `authorization code flow` with a `files` scope, to trigger user authentication at Azure AD. Azure AD then issues the app an access token with this scope. The app then sends this access token to APIs.

**BACKEND JOBS**

A Jenkins backend job is also an application. It uses the `client credentials flow` to send a credential to Azure AD to authenticate, then request a `files` scope. The credential can be a password or something stronger, eg a client certificate. The job then receives an access token with the requested scope, which it can send to APIs.

**APIs**

The APIs validate the JWT access token on every request, and return a 401 unauthorized response if this fails. The API also checks for the `files` scope. If this is not present the request is rejected with a 403 forbidden response. API authorization works in exactly the same way for both users and backend jobs.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your answer. I have updated my question and tried to explain better what I am trying to do. Basically, I am looking for a way to authenticate user in a non interactive way and hopefully in a way that doesn't need me to write and send a script to end user. I am hoping end user can use curl to authenticate and call the API

Comment: Could you give me more detail on how to use client credentials flow with Jenkins job? I am completely new to Azure/OIDC. I tried "Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow" page on Microsoft website and some other pages but I didn't understand the process. Normally, our Jenkins servers just run some jobs locally and I am not sure if they store any certificate or key somewhere. The only key/password that I am aware of on those Jenkins servers, is ssh key for git access.

Comment: Well a system like Jenkins can run bash scripts. Those scripts can use OAuth to get tokens then call APIs, eg using the curl tool - as in [this online repo](https://github.com/please-openit/oidc-bash-client/blob/master/oidc-client.sh). For a more advanced client, you might make Jenkins execute within a Docker container that contains a Node.js program. It could then run a bash script that kicks off Node.js code, eg by running npm start.

Comment: I already considered this solution for Jenkins but I didn't want to write a script for client. I thought maybe there is a way to get OAuth token using curl  and then send it to the API but I guess there isn't(The only one that I have seen with curl is using client secret which does not apply to my scenario.). Also, is OAuth token the same as access token?